# Creating tabs in markdown

Tags: css, math, markdown, mathjax

How would I be able to indent the `G(2)` and `G(1)` so that they are inline just below the 2 expressions. `G(2)` being just below `[16/4..]` and G(1) being just below `[1/4..]`. How would I be able to do such a thing in markdown?

```
$$[\frac{16}{4}-3(\frac{4}{2})+2] - [\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}+1] $$
G(2)  - G(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `underbrace` command:

```
$$\underbrace{\left[\frac{16}{4}-3\left(\frac{4}{2}\right)+2\right]}_{G(2)} - \underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}+1\right]}_{G(1)}$$
```

[image]

Comment: Your equation has no background, which makes it hard to read in dark mode. Just fyi :)